# Apostol's Calculus Volume 1, Theorem 2.9

Tags: calculus

In Apostol's Calculus Volume 1, Theorem 2.9, he proves that if $f$ is increasing on some closed interval, then the indefinite integral is convex.

In his argument, we have the inequality $f(t) \leq f(z)$ if $x \leq t \leq z$. Then the inequality is integrated, giving, $\int_{x}^z f(t) \,dt \leq f(z)(z-x)$

I can't quite see the justification for the right-hand side.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context?

Comment: First of all, Apostol would never have written $\int_x^z f(z)\,dz$. He would write $\int_x^z f(t)\,dt$. Do you understand why? And the right-hand side is likewise incorrect. This should be $f(c)(z-x)$ for some $c$ between $x$ and $z$. There is no justification for a false statement.

Comment: What Apostol actually wrote is $\int_x^z f(t)\,dt \le f(z)(z - x)$.

Comment: Thanks @BrianMoehring. Does my edit clarify?

Comment: @BrianMoehring, that's exactly right.  Apostol says that $f(t) \le f(z)$ for $x \le t \le z$, and then he says that integrating this inequality leads to his conclusion.

Comment: When Apostol suggests "integrating the inequality," the variable of integration is $t$.  So the right-hand side is $\int_x^z f(z)\,dt$.  In this integral, $f(z)$ is a constant.

Comment: Ahh, yes, thank you @DanVelleman.

Comment: Apostol gives a line by line proof on p122-123.  Which specific step are you unsure about?

Comment: Not sure how I can accept an answer, but @DanVelleman helped me.

Comment: If the derivative of $ F(x)$ is increasing then $F(x)$ is convex. The proof can be performed by applying the mean value theorem.